# Can I do a regex on a capturegroup in the same regex?

Tags: regex

I have a regex `(?i)(?<=srcset=\")([^\"]+)` that matches the content of a srcset in the htmlsource of a page. It's working. Now what I would like is to extract all the urls from the capturegroup with something like `http[^ ]+` - but I can only get one, no matter what I try.

Here is an example: `(?i)(?<=srcset=\")((http[^\s]+).*?)+(?=\")`

The catch is:
It's important that both operations is merged in one expression.

Any ideas?

sourcecode:

```
srcset="https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home.png 793w, https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-300x201.png 300w, https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-768x514.png 768w, https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-700x469.png 700w"
```

Comment: What language are you working in? In JS if you use match you will only get the first result, and you need to use matchAll and use the \g global attribute at the end.

Comment: What you ask for is impossible, but depending on the regex flavor you can adjust the regex pattern to match multiple occurrences of what you need.

Comment: If [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) is supported, you can use e.g. [`(?i)(?:\G(?!^)|srcset=")[^"]*?\b(https?:[^"\s,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/mDzJ5P/2)

Comment: Regex are not HTML parser

Comment: bobble bubble saves the day!!!  Exactly what I wanted - clean and beautiful - I just didn't know the syntax . Thanks from Denmark

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`\G` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) to chain matches if supported:

```
(?i)(?:\G(?!^)|srcset=")[^"]*?\b(https?:[^"\s,]+)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mDzJ5P/2)

- `(?:\G(?!^)|srcset=")` [either](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matches `srcset="` or continues at previous match
- `[^"]*?` matches [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) double quotes [lazyily](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution)  (between the links)
- `\b(https?:[^"\s,]+)` [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) links to *first group* starting at a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 0):

With `xidel`, a proper HTML parser, using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
xidel -e 'tokenize(//img/@srcset, "\s+\w+,?\s*")' -s file.html
```

### Output

```
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home.png
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-300x201.png
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-768x514.png
https://www.thesite.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/logo-home-700x469.png
```

Comment: You don't need `grep`: `-e 'tokenize(//img/@srcset,", ") ! tokenize(.)[1]'`.

Comment: `err:XPST0017: unknown function: tokenize #1` xidel `Xidel 0.9.8`

Comment: In that case use `-e 'tokenize(//img/@srcset,", ") ! tokenize(.,"\s")[1]'`, but you should really start using [v0.9.9](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/)!

Comment: @Reino: what can I read to understand `! tokenize(.)[1]` ?

Comment: [`tokenize()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-tokenize), but if you mean the `!`, then take a look at [Path operator (/)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-path-operator) vs. [Simple map operator (!)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator).